# allowframebreaks in Beamer theme

Tags: beamer, themes, beamerposter, allowframebreaks

I've build a Beamer theme a while ago. After some time of use I noticed that if the text is to long the frame will not display the remaining text on another frame. To fix that a new frame title was used. A little bit of research and I found the option `[allowframebreaks]`. This option is often used ìn addition to `begin{frame}`. I've tried to use it in combination with a couple of `setbeamertemplate{}` variants. The problem is that either the background canvas of the titlepage is duplicated or a big part of the text isn't displayed.

My **beameroutertheme.sty** looks like this:

```
 \mode<presentation>

    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
        \transparent{0.4}\hspace*{-0.2cm}\includegraphics[width=1.03\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{images/title.png}
    }
    
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=.8cm,dp=1ex,left]{footline}%
            \hspace*{3.2cm}\includegraphics[width=2.7cm]{images/logo.png}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }

    \defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mydefault}[1][]{
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \begingroup
            \begin{columns}
                \column{0.365\paperwidth}% Here
                    \mbox{}
                \column{0.635\paperwidth}% Here
                \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
                    \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
                \end{beamercolorbox}%
                \vspace*{0.9cm}
                \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{subtitle}
                    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
                    \else%
                        \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par%
                    \fi%     
                \end{beamercolorbox}%
                \vspace*{0.8cm}
                \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
                    \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
                \end{beamercolorbox}
                \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
                    \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
                \end{beamercolorbox}
            \end{columns}
        \endgroup
        \vfill
    }

    \setbeamertemplate{title page}[mydefault][]

    \BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%}
        \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
            \vspace*{-0.05cm}\insertframetitle

            \vspace*{-0.2cm}\hspace*{-.1cm}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=.05cm]{headline}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }
        %backgroundpicture to white
        \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
        }

        \setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.25cm,ht=\paperheight,dp=1ex,right]{sidebar left}%
           
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }
        %Fußzeile
        \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
            \hspace*{0.5cm}\vspace*{0.2cm}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=13cm,ht=.018cm,center]{footline}%

            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \begingroup
                \begin{columns}
                    \column{0.5\paperwidth}
                        \hspace*{0.95cm}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.5\paperwidth,ht=0.1cm,dp=1ex,left]{title}%
                            \usebeamerfont*{author in head/foot}\insertauthor%        
                        \end{beamercolorbox} 
                    \column{0.5\paperwidth}
                        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.5\paperwidth,ht=0.1cm,dp=1ex,center]{title}%
                            \hspace*{2cm}\insertframenumber
                        \end{beamercolorbox} 
                \end{columns}
            \endgroup
        }
    }
\mode<all>
```

Is in my case the `[allowframebreaks]` option really required or is there a better way?
How can I get the automatic framebreak I need?

Comment: To quote the beamer user guide: `The use of this option is evil. In a (good) presentation you prepare each slide carefully and think twice before putting something on a certain slide rather than on some different slide. Using the allowframebreaks option invites the creation of horrible, endless presentations that resemble more a “paper projected on the wall” than a presentation.`